# Finding the most recent date in SQL for a range of rows

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, max, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table of course work marks, with the table headings:

Module code, coursework numbers, student, date submitted, mark

Sample data in order of table headings:

Maths, 1, Parry, 12-JUN-92, 20

Maths, 2, Parry, 13-JUN-92, 20

Maths, 2, Parry, 15-JUN-92, 25

Expected data after query

Maths, 1, Parry, 12-JUN-92, 20

Maths, 2, Parry, 15-JUN-92, 25

Sometimes a student retakes an exam and they have an additional row for a piece of coursework.
I need to try get only the latest coursework’s in a table. The following works when I isolate a particular student:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE
WHERE NAME = ‘NAME’
AND DATE IN (SELECT MAX(DATE)
            FROM TABLE 
            WHERE NAME = ‘NAME’
            GROUP BY MODULE_CODE, COURSEWORK_NUMBER, STUDENT)
```

This provides the correct solution for that person, giving me the most recent dates for each row (each coursework) in the table. However, this:

```
 SELECT * 
FROM TABLE
AND DATE IN (SELECT MAX(DATE)
             FROM TABLE 
             GROUP BY MODULE_CODE, COURSEWORK_NUMBER, STUDENT)
```

Does not provide me with the same table but for every person who has attempted the coursework. Where am I going wrong? Sorry if the details are a bit sparse, but I’m worried about plagiarism.

Working with SQL plus

Comment: Hi.  please edit your question text (not in these comments), and show the sample data and expected output.  thanks

Comment: MAX_BY may work here.

Comment: @OldProgrammer I've added the sample and expected output

Comment: @Harry You indicated in your comment that my answer was correct. Could you please mark it as such, or at least upvote it?

Comment: @PanChristensen I have upvoted it. Not sure how to mark the correct answer, or if I have permission to do so

Comment: You (and only you) can mark the correct answer to your own question. Only you know if the answer solved your problem. Here's how: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

This is a good spot to use Oracle `keep` syntax:

```
select
    module_code,
    course_work_number,
    student,
    max(date_submitted) date_submitted,
    max(mark) keep(dense_rank first order by date_submitted desc) mark
from mytable
group by module_code, course_work_number, student
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6a3287cfdd4f5466690a603327032a83)**:

```
MODULE_CODE | COURSE_WORK_NUMBER | STUDENT | DATE_SUBMITTED | MARK
:---------- | -----------------: | :------ | :------------- | ---:
Maths       |                  1 | Parry   | 12-JUN-92      |   20
Maths       |                  2 | Parry   | 15-JUN-92      |   25
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a groupwise maximum. See this article from MySQL:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html
I'm not sure about the correct syntax for Oracle, but it should be similar. At least the query structure should put you on the right path.

Comment: Thanks, the link provided the answer, and I was looking for a groupwise maximum.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the row_number function to solve this:

```
select x.*
(SELECT a.*,row_number() over(partition by name order by date desc) as row1
FROM TABLE a)x
where x.row1=1
```

The idea is to assign a row number based on the date and then select the cases where row number is 1. Hope this helps.